# SDE $Y_t=Y_0+W_t +\int_{0}^t \gamma(Y_s) ds$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

- Let  $a,b :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
- Suppose $a$ to be of class $C^1$ and $b$ continuous.
- Suppose that $a(x) >0$ for every $x \in [0,T]$
- Let $h :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x)= \int_{0}^x \frac{1}{a(y)}dy$
- Suppose $ \int_{- \infty}^0 \frac{1}{a(y)}dy = \int_{0}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{a(y)}dy$
- $\gamma= \left( \frac{b}{a} - \frac{a'}{2} \right) \circ  h ^ {-1}$

Let $X$ be a solution of $X_t =X_0 + \int_{0}^t a(X_s) dW_s + \int_{0}^t b(X_s) ds, t \in [0,T]$

1. Show that $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection of class $C^2$
2. Show that $Y=h(X_t)$ solves $Y_t=Y_0+W_t +\int_{0}^t \gamma(Y_s) ds$
3. Determine $\tilde{b} : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ solves
   $X_t= X_0 + \int_{0}^t a(X_s) \circ dWs + \int_{0}^t \tilde{b}(X_s) ds , t \in [0,T]$,

$\circ$ means here the Stratonovitch equation.

---

1. $h'= \frac{1}{a} >0$ sp $h$ strictly increasing so bijective, and $\frac1a$ derivable, so $h$ is class $C^²$
2. 

$
\begin{align*}
dY_t&= h'(X_t) + \frac12 h''(X_t) d[X]_t  \\
    &= h'(X_t) dX_t +\frac12 \left( - \frac{a'(X_t)}{a^2(X_t)} a^2(X_t) dt \right) \\
&= \frac{a(X_t)}{a(X_t)} dW_t +  [ \dfrac{b(X_t) }{a(X_t)} - \dfrac{a'(X_t)}{2} ] ds\\
&= dW_t + [ \frac{b}{a} - \frac{a'}{2}](X_t) dt \\
&= dW_t + [ \frac{b}{a} - \frac{a'}{2}]\circ h^{-1}(Y_t) dt \\
\end{align*}
$
\

Answer (score 1):

$
 \begin{align*}
[a(X),W]_t&= \int_{0}^t a'(X_s) d[X,W]\\
          &=  \int_{0}^t a'(X_s)  a(X_s)d[W,W]  \\
          &=\int_{0}^t a'(X_s)  a(X_s)ds  \\
\int_{0}^{t} a(X_s) \circ dW&=\int_{0}^{t} a(X_s) dWs + \dfrac12 [a(X),W]_s\\
&=\int_{0}^{t} a(X_s) dWs + \dfrac12 a'(X_s)  a(X_s)ds \\
X_t&= X_0+ \int_{0}^{t} a(X_s) dWs + \dfrac12 \int_0^t a'(X_s)  a(X_s)ds -  \dfrac12 \int_0^t a'(X_s)  a(X_s)ds+\int_0^t b(X_s)ds \\
&=X_0+ \int_{0}^{t} a(X_s) \circ dWs + \int_0^t  - \dfrac12 a'(X_s)  a(X_s) + b(X_s) ds \\
 \tilde{b}(X_s)&= - \dfrac12 a'(X_s)  a(X_s) + b(X_s) 
\end{align*}
$

Is it correct ? Thanks.